# What's the Rust way to modify a structure within nested loops?

Tags: rust

Given is an array of bodies that interact in some way with each other. As a newbie I approached it as I would do it in some other language:

```
struct Body {
    x: i16,
    y: i16,
    v: i16,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bodies = Vec::<Body>::new();

    bodies.push(Body { x: 10, y: 10, v: 0 });
    bodies.push(Body { x: 20, y: 30, v: 0 });

    // keep it simple and loop only twice
    for i in 0..2 {
        println!("Turn {}", i);
        for b_outer in bodies.iter() {
            println!("x:{}, y:{}, v:{}", b_outer.x, b_outer.y, b_outer.v);
            let mut a = b_outer.v;
            for b_inner in bodies.iter() {
                // for simplicity I ignore here to continue in case b_outer == b_inner
                // just do some calculation
                a = a + b_outer.x * b_inner.x;
                println!(
                    "    x:{}, y:{}, v:{}, a:{}",
                    b_inner.x,
                    b_inner.y,
                    b_inner.v,
                    a
                );
            }
            // updating b_outer.v fails
            b_outer.v = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Updating of `b_outer.v` after the inner loop has finished fails:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to immutable field `b_outer.v`
  --> src/main.rs:32:13
   |
32 |             b_outer.v = a;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot mutably borrow immutable field
```

Making `b_outer` mutable:

```
for b_outer in bodies.iter_mut() { ...
```

doesn't work either:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `bodies` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:19:32
   |
16 |             for b_outer in bodies.iter() {
   |                            ------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
19 |                 for b_inner in bodies.iter_mut() {
   |                                ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
33 |             }
   |             - immutable borrow ends here
```

Now I'm stuck. What's the Rust approach to update `b_outer.v` after the inner loop has finished?

Comment: In your case, I think you could try `Vec<Cell<Body>>`, because `Cell` have "inner mutability".

Comment: Note: I ignored the "obvious" answer here, create a clone of `bodies`, and modify the clone while you iterate on `bodies`. It has the obvious disadvantage of requiring twice as much memory.

Comment: @MatthieuM. see my answer - I think modifying the array in-place during iteration is *incorrect* for this problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Ah, I did not think about challenging the logic :)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I think the error message is telling you that your code has a logic problem. If you update the vector between iterations of the inner loop, then *those changes will be used for subsequent iterations*. Let's look at a smaller example where we compute the windowed-average of an array item and its neighbors:

```
[2, 0, 2, 0, 2] // input
[2/3, 4/3, 2/3, 4/3, 2/3] // expected output (out-of-bounds counts as 0)

[2/3, 0,      2, 0, 2] // input after round 1
[2/3, 8/9,    2, 0, 2] // input after round 2
[2/3, 8/9, 26/9, 0, 2] // input after round 3
// I got bored here
```

I'd suggest computing the output into a temporary vector and then swap them:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Body {
    x: i16,
    y: i16,
    v: i16,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bodies = vec![Body { x: 10, y: 10, v: 0 }, Body { x: 20, y: 30, v: 0 }];

    for _ in 0..2 {
        let next_bodies = bodies
            .iter()
            .map(|b| {
                let next_v = bodies
                    .iter()
                    .fold(b.v, { |a, b_inner| a + b.x * b_inner.x });
                Body { v: next_v, ..*b }
            })
            .collect();
        bodies = next_bodies;
    }

    println!("{:?}", bodies);
}
```

Output:

```
[Body { x: 10, y: 10, v: 600 }, Body { x: 20, y: 30, v: 1200 }]
```

If you really concerned about memory performance, you could create a total of two vectors, size them appropriately, then alternate between the two. The code would be uglier though.

---

As Matthieu M. said, you *could* use [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), which both grant you inner mutability:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Body {
    x: i16,
    y: i16,
    v: i16,
}

fn main() {
    let bodies = vec![
        Cell::new(Body { x: 10, y: 10, v: 0 }),
        Cell::new(Body { x: 20, y: 30, v: 0 }),
    ];

    for _ in 0..2 {
        for b_outer_cell in &bodies {
            let mut b_outer = b_outer_cell.get();

            let mut a = b_outer.v;
            for b_inner in &bodies {
                let b_inner = b_inner.get();
                a = a + b_outer.x * b_inner.x;
            }
            b_outer.v = a;
            b_outer_cell.set(b_outer);
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", bodies);
}
```

```
[Cell { value: Body { x: 10, y: 10, v: 600 } }, Cell { value: Body { x: 20, y: 30, v: 1200 } }]
```

Comment: Concerning the logic problem, I would agree if b.v is changed during the inner loop (b_inner). But that's not the case. v of the inner body (b_inner) is not changed during the inner loop. b.v is updated after the inner loop has finished. Then b_outer advances to the next body.

Comment: I came up with another solution in the meantime (though I don't know if this is more elegant): I split the structure, one that is the base for the calculation (input) and another that gathers the results (output). After the calculation finished, the input structure is updated with results from the output structure and the next turn of the calculation starts.

Comment: I wonder what a solution using Cell would look like. I'm trying to rewrite his first code using Cells but I keep stumbling upon the original problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster That was fast, thanks! I figured you'd have to derive `Copy, Clone` in order to use `get`.  I'm writing an answer to share my findings as well, though I'm only learning Rust.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is like 2 years old, but I got curious about it.

This C# program produces the original desired output:

```
var bodies = new[] { new Body { X = 10, Y = 10, V = 0 },
                     new Body { X = 20, Y = 30, V = 0 } };

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Turn {0}", i);

    foreach (var bOuter in bodies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("x:{0}, y:{1}, v:{2}", bOuter.X, bOuter.Y, bOuter.V);
        var a = bOuter.V;
        foreach (var bInner in bodies)
        {
            a = a + bOuter.X * bInner.X;
            Console.WriteLine("    x:{0}, y:{1}, v:{2}, a:{3}", bInner.X, bInner.Y, bInner.V, a);
        }
        bOuter.V = a;
    }
}
```

Since only `v` is ever changed, we *could* change the struct to something like this:

```
struct Body {
    x: i16,
    y: i16,
    v: Cell<i16>,
}
```

Now I'm able to mutate `v`, and the program becomes:

```
// keep it simple and loop only twice
for i in 0..2 {
    println!("Turn {}", i);
    for b_outer in bodies.iter() {

        let mut a = b_outer.v.get();

        println!("x:{}, y:{}, v:{}", b_outer.x, b_outer.y, a);
        for b_inner in bodies.iter() {

            a = a + (b_outer.x * b_inner.x);

            println!(
                "    x:{}, y:{}, v:{}, a:{}",
                b_inner.x,
                b_inner.y,
                b_inner.v.get(),
                a
            );
        }

        b_outer.v.set(a);
    }
}
```

It produces the same output as the C# program above. The "downside" is that whenever you want to work with `v`, you need use `get()` or `into_inner()`. There may be other downsides I'm not aware of.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. This has the benefit of being very explicit about exactly what is able to be changed during the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to split the structure in one that is used as a base for the calculation (input) in the inner loop (`b_inner`) and one that gathers the results (output). After the inner loop finished, the input structure is updated in the outer loop (`b_outer`) and calculation starts with the next body.

What's now not so nice that I have to deal with two structures and you don't see their relation from the declaration.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Body {
    x: i16,
    y: i16,
}

struct Velocity {
    vx: i16,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bodies = Vec::<Body>::new();
    let mut velocities = Vec::<Velocity>::new();

    bodies.push(Body { x: 10, y: 10 });
    bodies.push(Body { x: 20, y: 30 });
    velocities.push(Velocity { vx: 0 });
    velocities.push(Velocity { vx: 0 });

    // keep it simple and loop only twice
    for i in 0..2 {
        println!("Turn {}", i);
        for (i, b_outer) in bodies.iter().enumerate() {
            println!("x:{}, y:{}, v:{}", b_outer.x, b_outer.y, velocities[i].vx);
            let v = velocities.get_mut(i).unwrap();
            let mut a = v.vx;
            for b_inner in bodies.iter() {
                // for simplicity I ignore here to continue in case b_outer == b_inner
                // just do some calculation
                a = a + b_outer.x * b_inner.x;
                println!("    x:{}, y:{}, v:{}, a:{}", b_inner.x, b_inner.y, v.vx, a);
            }
            v.vx = a;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", bodies);
}
```

Output:

```
[Body { x: 10, y: 10 }, Body { x: 20, y: 30 }]
```

Comment: Just want to point out that these changes may not reflect the original intent. Of course, the end result is the same in both cases, but the stdout is slightly different.